# Failing to setup ondelete Cascade with Code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the Client class and the dependant MatriculaCliente class, they have a one(client) to many relationship and i need the ondelete cascade to delete all clients matricula's after the client is delete, not sure why is not working this is how im tryng to do

Client

```
public class Cliente
{
    [Key]
    public string CONCLIENTE { get; set; }
    public string tipoDocumentoCliente { get; set; }
    public string nomeCliente { get; set; }          
    public string escolaridadeCliente { get; set; }

    public ICollection<MatriculaCliente> matriculas { get; set; }

    public Cliente() {
        matriculas = new Collection<MatriculaCliente>();
    }
}
```

Matricula

```
public class MatriculaCliente
{
    [Key]
    public string conmatriculacliente { get; set; }

    public string concliente { get; set; }
    public Cliente cliente { get; set; }
    public string tipoDocumento { get; set; }
    public string descricaoNegocio { get; set; }
    public string matriculaCliente { get; set; }
}
```

this is my migration history where u can see the ondelete is restrict

```
    public partial class ModeloClienteMatricula : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Clientes",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    CONCLIENTE = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    cepCliente = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    cpfCliente = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    dataDeclaracaoPepCliente = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                    dataNascimentoCliente = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                    escolaridadeCliente = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    estadoCivilCliente = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    nomeCliente = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    rendaCliente = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    sexoCliente = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    tipoDocumentoCliente = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Clientes", x => x.CONCLIENTE);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Matriculas",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    conmatriculacliente = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    concliente = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    descricaoNegocio = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    matriculaCliente = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    tipoDocumento = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Matriculas", x => x.conmatriculacliente);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Matriculas_Clientes_concliente",
                        column: x => x.concliente,
                        principalTable: "Clientes",
                        principalColumn: "CONCLIENTE",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Matriculas_concliente",
                table: "Matriculas",
                column: "concliente");
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Matriculas");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Clientes");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code that "is not working" and explain *how* it's not working. Also, what's the database tables' create script?

Comment: those are the entites. what is the model?

Comment: updated the code with the migration history, where u can see the ondelete restrict

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the fluent API to do this.

Try adding the following to your DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{   
    modelBuilder.Entity<Cliente>()
        .HasOptional(a => a.matriculas)
        .WithOptionalDependent()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

Comment: this worked for me protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Cliente>()
        .HasMany(c => c.matriculas)
        .WithOne(e => e.Cliente)
        .IsRequired();
}

Comment: Ok. That's another way to do it. My approach will also work. Did you try it?